# В чем отличие XMLHttpRequest от jQuery.ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

И `XMLHttpRequest` и `jQuery.ajax` запросы оба необходимы для запроса на сервер без перезагрузки страницы. Соответственно вопрос.

1. В чем преимущества одного типа над другим?
2. Когда лучше использовать `XMLHttpRequest` а когда `$.ajax` запрос?

Comment: jquery.ajax физически использует xhr внутри себя.

Answer (score 6):

- `XMLHttpRequest` - это интерфейс к возможностям работы с сетью
  (ограниченно, конечно), предоставляемый браузером.
- `jQuery.ajax` -
  это интерфейс к `XMLHttpRequest`, предоставляемой библиотекой
  `jQuery`.
  Кто-то скажет что более удобный, чем браузерный.
- `jQuery.post` - это интерфейс к `jQuery.ajax` с настройками на `POST`
  запрос.
- ...

Т. е. всё пытаются сделать интерфейс, который будет максимально простым.
Даже не знаю насколько это хорошо в перспективе.

Answer (score 4):

`jQuery.ajax` это "обертка" над `XMLHttpRequest`

Так что стоит использовать `XMLHttpRequest` только тогда, когда нет возможности подключить `jQuery`